# Get range of index for binary search with multiple matches

Tags: javascript, binary-search

So, I'm working on this searching algorithm and I'm trying to implement binary search. The search function itself will take the user's input and supposed to show everything that starts with these characters, so, evidently, there is a probability that there should be more than one entry to be the answer (for example, query "woo" should also shows "wood" and "wool").

This is what I've wrote so far:

```
let binarySearch = (array, target, startIndex, endIndex) => {
    let start = startIndex;
    let end = endIndex;
//if there's no result
    if (start > end) {
        return -1;
    }

    while(start <= end) {
        let middleIndex = Math.floor((start+end)/2);
        if (array[middleIndex].toLowerCase().includes(target.toLowerCase())) {
            return middleIndex;
        } else if (target.toLowerCase().localeCompare(array[middleIndex].toLowerCase()) < 0) {
            end = middleIndex - 1;
        } else if (target.toLowerCase().localeCompare(array[middleIndex].toLowerCase()) > 0) {
            start = middleIndex +1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
};

let binarySearchMultiple = (array, target) => {
    let firstMatch = binarySearch(array, target, 0, array.length-1);
    let resultArr = [-1, -1];
//if there's no match
    if (firstMatch == -1) {
        return resultArr;
    }

    let leftMost = firstMatch;
    let rightMost = firstMatch;

    //first half
    let firstHalfResult = binarySearch(array, target, 0, leftMost-1);
    //second half
    let secondHalfResult = binarySearch(array, target, rightMost+1, array.length-1);
    

    for (; firstHalfResult != -1;) {
        leftMost = firstHalfResult;
        firstHalfResult = binarySearch(array, target, 0, leftMost-1);
    };

    for (; secondHalfResult != -1;) {
        rightMost = secondHalfResult;
        secondHalfResult = binarySearch(array, target, rightMost+1, array.length-1);
    };

    resultArr[0] = firstHalfResult;
    resultArr[1] = secondHalfResult;

    return resultArr;
};
```

Basically, I tried to do a recursive function once the first entry found, to do the search again on the left and right side until there's no match anymore.

However, it doesn't work quite correctly, as when I tried to run it like this (I use a simplified short array to test it):

```
let testArr = ["aaa", "aab", "aac", "aad", "bbb", "bbc"];

console.log(binarySearchMultiple(testArr, "aa"));
```

the result was `[-1, undefined]`

I know I must have done something wrong on the recursive part, but I have been staring on it for days and I still don't get what I did wrong. As I am a total newbie in JavaScript, I hope that I could get a bit of an insight here.

Comment: What is the expected result? Is it prefix matching?

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi yes, my expected result supposed to be the index of the first time it matches until the last one, so like in the example I expect the result to be [0, 3]

Comment: @Bergi yes, I meant everything that starts with these characters, sorry if I wasn't too clear.